# VBA.net skipping line before function

Tags: vb.net

Why the  first portion of code is not running until the function is done.

```
            ' Below portion is not running untill programmer() funtion is finish
             Start_btn.Text = "STOP"
             Start_btn.BackColor = Color.Red
             Start_btn.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
             Timer1.Enabled = True                
             Prg_Label.Text = "Programming"  
             program_status.Text = "Wait Processing" 


                If (programmer() = True) Then  'This the function 
                    program_status.Text = "Success"
                    Start_btn.Text = "START"
                    Start_btn.BackColor = Color.Green
                    Start_btn.ForeColor = Color.White
                    Timer1.Enabled = False
                Else
                    program_status.Text = "Failed"
                    Start_btn.Text = "START"
                    Start_btn.BackColor = Color.Green
                    Start_btn.ForeColor = Color.White
                    Timer1.Enabled = False

                End If
```

Programmer function  will take a while to finish, and all is doing running some commands in command line.

How ever if I add massagebox before the function all line before the function everything works.

```
           Start_btn.Text = "STOP"
           Start_btn.BackColor = Color.Red
           Start_btn.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
           Timer1.Enabled = TruePrg_Label.Text = "Programming"  'Will Work
           program_status.Text = "Wait Processing" 
           MessageBox.Show("here")

            If (programmer() = True) Then
                program_status.Text = "Success"
                Start_btn.Text = "START"
                Start_btn.BackColor = Color.Green
                Start_btn.ForeColor = Color.White
                Timer1.Enabled = False
            Else
                program_status.Text = "Failed"
                Start_btn.Text = "START"
                Start_btn.BackColor = Color.Green
                Start_btn.ForeColor = Color.White
                Timer1.Enabled = False

            End If
```

Answer (score 1):

The lines are running (you'd be able to step through with breakpoints to see this), but the items on the form don't refresh until the function finishes. The MessageBox causes a refresh which is why it seems like it has run.

You can refresh individual controls (eg. `Start_btn.Refresh()`) or the entire form:

```
Start_btn.Text = "STOP"
Start_btn.BackColor = Color.Red
Start_btn.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
Timer1.Enabled = TruePrg_Label.Text = "Programming"  'Will Work
program_status.Text = "Wait Processing" 
MessageBox.Show("here")

Me.Refresh()

If (programmer() = True) Then
    program_status.Text = "Success"
    Start_btn.Text = "START"
    Start_btn.BackColor = Color.Green
    Start_btn.ForeColor = Color.White
    Timer1.Enabled = False
Else
    program_status.Text = "Failed"
    Start_btn.Text = "START"
    Start_btn.BackColor = Color.Green
    Start_btn.ForeColor = Color.White
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh the form, or you can do Application.DoEvents() to get it to update.

However, I guess since you notice the form doesn't update, and you are able to update the form from that method, you are running on a UI thread, and your `programmer` function actually takes some time. You should not run something which will hang the UI thread on the UI.

You can use `Async / Await` to allow the form to run smoothly

```vb
Private Async Sub waitForProgramming()
    setUIProcessing()
    setUIReady(If(Await programmerAsync(), "Success", "Failed"))
End Sub

Private Function programmerAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)
    Return Task.Run(AddressOf programmer)
End Function

Private Sub setUIProcessing()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() setUIProcessing())
    Else
        Start_btn.Text = "STOP"
        Start_btn.BackColor = Color.Red
        Start_btn.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
        Timer1.Enabled = TruePrg_Label.Text = "Programming"  'Will Work
        program_status.Text = "Wait Processing"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub setUIReady(status As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() setUIReady(status))
    Else
        Start_btn.Text = "START"
        Start_btn.BackColor = Color.Green
        Start_btn.ForeColor = Color.White
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        program_status.Text = status
    End If
End Sub
```